# Nginx deny ip not working when I use ddos denfence server as frontend

Tags: nginx, x-forwarded-for

I want add block IP address into nginx configure.But it still can be accessed using curl !

```
...
log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent $request_time "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" REALIP"$http_x_forwarded_for"';
location  / {
        include /usr/local/nginx/blockip.conf;
        root   html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
        proxy_set_header    Host             $host;
        proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header    HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme; 

        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
        }
...
```

the blockip.conf

```
deny 1.2.3.4;
deny 3.4.5.6;
```

There are two situations here.

1.Point to server directly using domain name (A record),blockip can work well.

2.When add ddos defence server,nginx deny rule not working anymore!

But I can get real IP from the nginx-access-log.
Here logs example:

```
defence-server-IP - - [23/Mar/2020:14:15:59 +0800] "GET /walle HTTP/1.1" 404 1079 0.001 "-" "curl/7.58.0" REALIP"1.2.3.4"
defence-server-IP - - [23/Mar/2020:14:16:07 +0800] "GET /walle HTTP/1.1" 404 1079 0.000 "-" "curl/7.58.0" REALIP"3.4.5.6"
```

## solution

By the way.I change nginx to openresty

```
server {
...
    set_real_ip_from defence-server-ip-ranges/24;
    ...
    real_ip_header X-Forwarded-For;
    include /usr/local/nginx/blockip.conf;
    
    location {...}
...
}
```

Comment: You need to use the [Real IP Module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_realip_module.html) to map the `$http_x_forwarded_for` value into `$remote_addr` so that `deny` operates on the correct value.

Comment: @RichardSmith I use python scripts dynamic extra real IP and write into block.conf ,then reload nginx. Is that add real IP module ,so that the nginx deny module can identify the real client IP ?

Comment: Yes. As you say in your question, you can see the real client IP in the logs. You need to set `real_ip_header ` and `set_real_ip_from`, so that Nginx knows which value to use.